# problemas con month calendar c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con `MonthCalendar` de `c#`, explicare brevemente...

Tengo un formulario donde obtiene fechas de una base de dato `SQL`,
al momento de encontrar fechas se marcan en negrito en el `MonthCalendar`.

Al hacer `click` en esa fecha me despliega un reporte que cree para que muestre información relacionada a esa fecha, pero al momento de cambiar de fecha, en la flechita de arriba, en cambio de mes o año, este se pega y empiezan a salir muchos reportes vacíos colapsando el software, necesito de su ayuda por favor.

```
private void monthCalendarProgramacion5_DateChanged (object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    try{
        //con esto puedo visualizar la fecha a la cual se selecciona y convertirla en string para pasarla a un textbox
        textBox5.Text = monthCalendarProgramacion5.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
        //se iniciliza el formulario reporte para visualizar los datos
        FormMostrarMonthCalendar4 month = new FormMostrarMonthCalendar4();
        //se pasa el dato en fecha al parametro del formulario reporte para el procedimiento
        month.fechaOT3 = monthCalendarProgramacion5.SelectionRange.Start.Date;
        //se iniciliza el formulario para mostrar los datos
        month.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fallo" + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar el evento

[MonthCalendar.DateSelected Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.dateselected?view=netframework-4.7.2)

a diferencia del `DateChanged` este se ejecuta cuando hay una seleccion concreta de la fecha

En la documentacion menciona

> Este evento es similar a la DateChanged evento, pero se produce al final de una selección de fecha realizada mediante el mouse. El DateChanged evento se produce durante cualquier selección de fecha, ya sea por el mouse, teclado o código

Comment: gracias, pero lo controle colocando un boton en el evento. asi no tengo problemas ahora. muchas gracias

Comment: si ok usar un evento de otro control lo soluciona, pero imagine querias aplicar el filtro seleccionando sobre el mismo calendar